# Datagrid view - Basics - combobox - textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Visual studio 2010 Express (Beginner) , I am using VB

Currently attempting Datagridview, I have 3 columns in my DGV - The 2nd column consists of a combobox cbo1 and 3rd column is a Textbox txt2. Column1 is the name of the person txt1

Country & Capital are the two columns in my 'mysql database'

I have added my database to a dataset named ds using the adapter,

```
    adp.Fill(ds)
    Country_cbo.DataSource = ds
    cbo1.DisplayMember = ds.Columns("Country").ToString
```

Using the above code I have managed to populate the cbo1 with Countries name (using mysql database)

Trying to Achieve:
Upon selecting a value from country name function should fill the textbox with the capital of the respective country by looking into the Data set ( Which is my Database )

A guideline to acheive this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataset has only one table, So `ds.Tables[0]` will give you the table in dataset.

Now the value is retrieved from the combo box as `combobox.SelectedItem.`

Then you can use a for loop to traverse through all rows of the ds.Tables[0] .

Compare the value of combo box with the column value in each row. If there is a match, retrieve the capital column's value of that row

Example for loop (C# syntax):

```
    foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)      
    {
        //Your logic here to perform comparison  
    }
```

Comment: I hope you got an idea now.. Else post your queries